# Windows 11 - How to remove entire recommended section from start menu (not just disable the apps in it)

Tags: windows-11

I'm looking for a way to remove the ENTIRE recommended section from the start menu, not only disable the apps.

I already disabled them but that leaves half the menu unused and I'd like to make space for more pins. Please see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 11?